# Sum of Squares of Primes

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have seen problems in the past along these lines:

> If integers $a$ and $b$ are prime and if $a^2+b^2+2017=m^2$, then find the two prime numbers.

I have no idea about how to approach this kind of problem.

Comment: Note that square numbers can only be $0$ or $1\pmod 4$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there are any good general methods, I think it comes down to finding out what you can in each specific case.

Here you could note that if $a,b$ are odd, then $a^2$ and $b^2$ have remainder $1$ when divided by $4$; so the LHS has remainder $3$ when divided by $4$; but the RHS cannot have remainder $3$.  So this is impossible.

If one of $a,b$ is odd and the other is even, then LHS has remainder $2$ when divided by $4$; but the RHS cannot have remainder $2$.  So this is also impossible.

Therefore the only possibility is $a=b=2$.  We then check that $a^2+b^2+2017$ is indeed a square, namely, $45^2$.